# ostream_iterator template parameters

Tags: c++

For the code below, why is there an error? ostream_iterator is a template class, so why isn't there a matching constructor to initialize it?  why i can user ostream_interator but not use ostream_iterator

```
define ostream_iterator template > class _LIBCPP_VISIBLE ostream_iterator

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
vector<int> sentence1;
sentence1.reserve(5);// 设置每次分配内存的大小

sentence1.push_back(1);
sentence1.push_back(2);
sentence1.push_back(3);
sentence1.push_back(4);
sentence1.push_back(5);

int c = 5;

copy(sentence1.begin(), sentence1.end(), ostream_iterator<int, int>(cout, &c));
cout << endl;
```

Comment: Your other question has a perfectly good answer. If you have a problem with it, please leave a comment on it.

Comment: @Best how come you're passing a `int *` as a delimiter after  answers from your other question indicates a `char *` is expected?

Comment: why i can't use two parameters like ostream_iterator<int, int>

Comment: Did you read the [doc here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ostream_iterator/)? `cout` uses `charT = char`. That's why your ostream_iterator is failing.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the other. In the other question the `std::ostream_iterator` was instantiated with the correct types, but the second argument to the constructor was wrong. In this case, the template instantiation is *wrong* (contrary to the desire of the programmer), and the answer is completely different.

Comment: @BestWater: Your problem is that you are providing the wrong set of template arguments to the `ostream_iterator` you want to provide a single `int` and leave the other two template arguments as defaulted (`std::ostream_iterator<int>`). **Then** the answers in the question marked as duplicate will help you.

Comment: The error message in gcc tells you the answer if you read it carefully: `no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ to ‘std::ostream_iterator<int, int>::ostream_type& {aka std::basic_ostream<int, std::char_traits<int> >&}’`, in other words: can't convert `char` stream to `int` stream.